# How to send/receive json object between JQuery and JSF (Myfaces Tomahawk component library)

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am using JSF(Myfaces Tomahawk component library) and jQuery. All I want is to send json object to jsf bean when i click a button and similarly send a json object(from jsf bean) to page when it's loading.

Answer (score 3):

Implement a custom [`ViewHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html) and/or [`PhaseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) which does the job. All you basically need to do is to hook on specific requests (ajaxical requests usually have a `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header) and have a reference to the associated JSF component tree in the session so that you can do the works on it.

This is however quite a work which requires a solid understanding of how JSF works under the hoods. Since you're already asking a trivial question like this, I think it's going to be a very long journey. I would then strongly recommend to just grab an existing component lirbary which enables using ajaxcal magics in JSF, like [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org), [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces), [OpenFaces](http://openfaces.org), [IceFaces](http://icefaces.org), [Trinidad](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/), etc. You'll be ready in a few hours instead of months.

Comment: So put simply, doing json seems quite esoteric when using JSF (MyFaces). And btw, explicitly making a question look so simple was intended to let in multiple solutions and not just one or two restricted (scenario-based) solutions.